# How can I combine multiple text files (specific line + metadata) into one .txt or .csv file with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, txt

I need to combine the 16th line + file name and creation date of multiple text files located inside a folder and add this information to a new single file (.txt or .csv).

The files content look like this (the layout is the same for every file):

```
BD  
C  
BEGIN_RUECKMELDUNG_FERTIGUNGAUFTRAG  
C  
ZA,MM,6  
MM,AT,1,10,1,1,,'JOBNAME',,,T  
MM,AT,1,20,1,1,,'ORDER_DESCRIPTION',,,T  
MM,AT,1,30,1,1,,'PROGRAM_NAME',,,T  
MM,AT,1,40,1,1,,'DESIRED_QTY',,,Z  
MM,AT,1,50,1,1,,'CURRENT_QTY',,,Z  
MM,AT,1,60,1,1,,'SHEET_RUNTIME',,,Z  
MM,AT,1,70,1,1,,'SUPPLY_STOCK_NAME',,,T  
MM,AT,1,80,1,1,,'BATCH_NUMBER',,,T  
C  
ZA,DA,1  
DA,'*','MACHINE','105759',1,1,869,'','*' <---- Line to get  
C  
ENDE_RUECKMELDUNG_FERTIGUNGAUFTRAG  
C  
ED
```

So the output file (in this example with 5 files combined) would look like this:

```
DA,'*','MACHINE','105759',1,1,869,'','*',filename,creationdate
DA,'*','MACHINE','103423',1,1,234,'','*',filename,creationdate
DA,'*','MACHINE','102562',1,1,2552,'','*',filename,creationdate
DA,'*','MACHINE','105667',1,1,742,'','*',filename,creationdate
DA,'*','MACHINE','105355',1,1,7332,'','*',filename,creationdate
```

So far I've been able to write two separate codes, one that combines the whole content of each file and one that combines the file names and creation date, but I can't combine this into one code, neither can I get only the 16th line of the files.

```
$folder = 'Z:\Brun\Test\maquina1'
$files = Get-ChildItem $folder\*.lst

Get-Content $files | Set-Content $folder\MergedTxtFileMaquina1.txt
```

```
$folder = 'Z:\Brun\Test\maquina1'
$files = Get-ChildItem $folder\*.lst

$files | Select Name,CreationTime,LastWriteTime
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I would use Select-String : $match = Select-String -Path $input_filename -Pattern '^DA,'

Answer (score 1):

To get the 16th line you can probably use a command like:

```
(Get-Content -Path .\StackOverFlow.txt -TotalCount 16)[-1]
```

Comment: I've done it for this post, but in the future please [format your posts properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).